# Laravel whereHas when the relation has a nested structure

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This question is more related to programming approach, but since it is utilizing Eloquent model relationships and my question is actually to try and simplify the executed queries from Eloquent, I decided to post it with the Laravel tag.

In a Laravel 5.8 app that I am working on, I have a relationship between my Item and Category model as given below:

Item Model

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Category Model

```
public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

My Item model have a boolean attribute called "active", so to get all categories which has active items, I can use a statement

```
Category::whereHas('items', function ($query) {
                            $query->active();
                        })->get();
```

Now, the Category structure is nested, meaning each category can have a parent category. The parent category id is available as the 'parent_id' attribute in the Category model, and it will be NULL if the category is the topmost level. So this relationship in the Category model looks like

```
public function parent_category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function subcategories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Finally, let me come to my question. What is the best way to get all categories with active items including subcategories without querying each category separately if it has active items or not? For example, if I have the below data

```
Category 1     (id=1,   parent_id=NULL, no active items)
Category 1.1   (id=11,  parent_id=1,     1 active item)
Category 2     (id=2,   parent_id=NULL, no active items)
Category 2.1   (id=21,  parent_id=2,    no active items)
Category 2.1.1 (id=211, parent_id=21,    1 active item)
Category 3     (id=3,   parent_id=NULL, no active items)
Category 3.1   (id=3.1, parent_id=3,    no active items)
```

I want to get all top level categories where even one of it's nested subcategory has an active item. In the above case, I would like to get Category 1 and Category 2 as my result.

Right now, I have to get the list of all categories and then go through each of its subcategories (and then each of the subcategory's subcategories until I find no subcategories) and determine if they any active items. Is there an elegant way to solve this, or what I am doing is already the best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I know I can have an extra database field to store the number of active items in each category and update it every time any of the item's active status changes (and update the parent category's field too if the category has a parent category). But the "active" field mentioned above is just an example, I need to look for variable fields like stock for example, i might need to get all categories where the stock is above 10 and this approach won't work there.